# Spoiled 1% milk

Tags: bacteriology

A friend of mine gave me a jug of 1% milk and when I got home to put it in my fridge I noticed that it was already out of date so I set it on the counter next to our trash can and at the time we didn't have a vehicle to holler trash off so it's not on my counter for about 3 days and all of a sudden one night me and my boyfriend are sitting there in a room and the milk just starts projectile shooting out of a hole that it made in the side of the jugs not out of the lid just spraying everywhere all over the kitchen and I want to know why it for 1 started spraying spoiled milk as if it was pressurized and for 2 how did it make its own hole in the plastic jug???

Answer (score 2):

Interesting story, well told. It ***was*** pressurized. When the microorganisms fermented the milk, they give off carbon dioxide, which builds up and creates pressure. This is why beer is carbonated. They did not however make the hole in the milk container directly. It was likely a weak spot that burst from the pressure.